# PHP array_push() warning expect array

Tags: php

I am trying to push multiple arrays into 1 big array. For this I use array_push() and it looks like this:

sample code:

```
$Rd=array();
array_push($Rd[count($Rd)-1], "a", "b", "c");
```

This code show me warning:

> PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

what I need

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ddd
            [1] => ffffffffffffffff
            [2] => ggggggg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fff
            [1] => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
            [2] => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
        )

)
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly add the key, you can just do `array_push($Rd, "a", "b");`

Comment: But i need to make array into array.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? To me it looks like your output could be done with array_chunk(), but that's what happens with not enough information in a question. I can tell you the warning is because `$Rd[count($Rd)-1]` isn't an array, but that doesn't solve what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need array push, as calling it gives you extra overhead, why not use something like this...

```
$Rd = array();
$Rd[] = ["ddd", "ffffffffffffffff", "ggggggg"];
$Rd[] = ["fff", "dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg", "dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
$Rd[count($Rd)-1]
```

Is an index minus 1 to a null array. So doing this:

```
array_push($Rd[count($Rd)-1], "a", "b", "c");
```

Parameter 1 will be null; you should do like this:

```
array_push($Rd, "a", "b", "c");
```

However, it is not clear if that's really what you want?